# How to increase the difficulty in Crysis 2?

Tags: pc, crysis-2

I had a bug in game which made me change difficulty to very easy. And now I am unable to increase the difficulty again after passing that chapter. How do I change the difficulty?

Comment: @Mana How "Is it possible to ..." is better than "How to ..."?

Comment: According to one of the studies that was done on question stats, forming a proper question in the title of your question ("How do I increase difficulty?" vs. "Increase difficulty") can increase the view count by 25%. Didn't really seem to matter here though, sorry. :(

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change difficulty mid-game.

However, you can replay a chapter with a desired difficulty, which seems to be the best compromise in your case.